# Performing calculations on multiple columns in dataframe and create new columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to perform calculations based on the entries in a `pandas` dataframe. The dataframe looks something like this:
[image]
and it contains 1466 rows. I'll have to run similar calculations on other `df`s with more rows later.

What I'm trying to do, is calculate something like `mag`=`'(U-V)/('R-I)'` (but ignoring any values that are -999), put that in a new column, and then `z_pred`=`10**((mag-c)m)` in a new column (`mag`, `c` and `m` are just hard-coded variables). I have other columns I need to add too, but I figure that'll just be an extension of the same method.

I started out by trying

```
for i in range(1):
    current = qso[:]
    mag = (U-V)/(R-I)
    name = current['NED']
    z_pred = 10**((mag - c)/m)
    z_meas = current['z']
```

but I got either a Series for `z`, which I couldn't operate on, or various type errors when I tried to print the values or write them to a file.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118240/perform-calculation-on-multiple-columns-at-once-with-pandas) which gave me a start, but I can't see how to apply it to multiple calculations, as in my situation.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if the answer is helpful please accept and upvote

Comment: I’ve accepted this as the answer, but I have some follow up questions. I’ll post them tomorrow.

Comment: ok, thanks. btw, did you upvote as well?

Comment: Yes, I upvoted this morning after trying your solution. The reason I didn’t label it as the accepted answer, was those follow up questions I mentioned.

Comment: ah ok, think you'd better post them in another question though

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionally adding calculated columns row wise are usually performed with `numpy`'s `np.where`;

```
df['mag'] = np.where(~df[['U', 'V', 'R', 'I']].eq(-999).any(1), (df.U - df.V) / (df.R - df.I), -999)
```

Note; assuming here that when any of the columns contain '-999' it will not be calculated and a '-999' is returned.

Comment: What is the meaning of `.eq(-999).any(1)` in the expression in your answer? I'm guessing the `.eq(-999)` means `== -999`.

Comment: here is does, and you'd might try to use `==` instead. for additional info take a look at this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410178/why-is-pandas-different-than-eq